# Bulk API 2.0: Can I insert AND upsert in one csv request?

Tags: batch, csv, upsert, insert, bulk-api-v2

**Edited to clarify:**

Background info on what I'm working on – we're going to be receiving email lists from clients, and we want to create new Leads or update existing Leads in Salesforce with the info we receive in these email list. I'm building out a batch request process using the Bulk API 2.0 for creating/updating Leads.

Since I won't know if the Leads exist or not, my current process loops through each request individually (by their email addresses) to determine if they need to be inserted or upserted and batches them accordingly, but I feel like this defeats the purpose of batch handling if I'm still processing each request one by one first.

I've already read through this doc: [Bulk Upsert](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/walkthrough_upsert.htm)

I understand that the records need a unique identifier/custom external ID in Salesforce, and I can set that up in Salesforce... but my question is regarding the CSV I'm compiling for the API – the clients aren't going to know the corresponding custom ID we have in Salesforce for the email addresses they give us, and when creating the CSV for the batch request, I can't look up Leads by a value I don't have.

Unfortunately, email addresses aren't unique, so I can't use that as the identifier. Is there another way we can handle this processing in one CSV request?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/walkthrough_upsert.htm

Comment: @identigral That should be an answer. Go ahead, you deserve the rep!

Comment: @identigral - I saw that, and I see that it says "Some of the records exist (update), and some are new records (insert)," but I think what's confusing me is that each row in the example csv has values for the 'customExtIdField__c' column. If I don't know if it exists, how would I populate that value?

Comment: You need it on all records: _Upserting records requires an external ID field on the object involved in the job. Bulk API 2.0 uses the external ID field to determine whether a record is used to update an existing record or create a record_

Comment: Thanks, but I think you guys misunderstood my question  I edited my question to clarify and give context.

Comment: Based on that information you've added, the simple answer would be not as it currently stands. You need to be able to identify the records uniquely so that the Upsert functionality can identify if it is updating or inserting. Given email isn't unique, you need to look at how you can construct a unique key for each record based on a combination of field values that your csv will contain. The important thing with that though, is that a. you'd need to also update existing leads with that key, and b. ensure that it's not going to change if the fields in Salesforce are updated later.

Comment: @CallumMacErlich - I didn't think about building a unique identifier out of other field values. That's definitely doable and gives me something to work with. Thank you! 